# Expand wlan with a wlan router or access point

Tags: networking, router, wifi, access-point, wlan

My wish is to expand the WLAN network, because of aborted connections.

That means, the "central" router gives the internet connection in the LAN and the other router/access point uses the LAN connection to spread it through the WLAN. LAN Ports are available at the installation site of the new additional router/access point.

What is the smarter way to expand the WLAN range: a WLAN router or a WLAN access point? Where are the biggest differences between them? Are there some advantages to use a WLAN access point? Or does a WLAN router do the same if it is correct configured?

Should i buy a WLAN router from TP-Link (TL-WR841ND) or a WLAN access point (TL-WA801ND). The price is almost the same. Or do you have some other suggestions of a WLAN router/access point?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

`What is the smarter way to expand the WLAN range: a WLAN router or a WLAN access point?` Using a Wireless Access Point.

`Where are the biggest differences between them?` One is a router and the other is not.

`Are there some advantages to use a WLAN access point?` Yes. It's the right tool for the job, so that's the advantage.

`Or does a WLAN router do the same if it is correct configured?` - Yes, but why would you use a router when all you need is an Access Point?

Answer (score 0):

You can think of the access point as a bridge that extends the LAN.  When you connect to the access point, it is the same (logically) as connecting via wire to the "central" router.

You can use a wireless router, but it makes the network more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a router already, and don't need to segregate the clients of the new WLAN in some unique way (i.e. they are low trust devices that should not be allowed near your other devices) then you should never complicate your network by introducing another router.  Use the access point version, set the SSID to match your current one, so that your devices can freely choose whichever signal is stronger.